# cassandra select query failed with code=1300

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have a Cassandra cluster of 4 nodes with replication factor of 3, we have about 400M records on table1 and after restarting the cluster I got the following error when selecting from the table

```
ReadFailure: Error from server: code=1300 [Replica(s) failed to execute read] message="Operation failed - received 0 responses and 1 failures" info={'failures': 1, 'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'ONE'}
```

We tried these queries on cqlsh

```
select id from table1; ----> Failed
select id from table1 limit 10; -----> Failed
select id from table1 limit 1; ----> Succeed
select id form table1 where id=22; ----> Succeed
select id from othertable; ----> Succeed
```

And the schema for the table is:

```
    CREATE TABLE ks.table1 (
    id int, 
    name text,
PRIMARY KEY (id))
            WITH read_repair_chance = 0.0
           AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
           AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
           AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
           AND caching = { 'keys' : 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition' : 'NONE' }
           AND comment = ''
           AND compaction = { 'class' : 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.LeveledCompactionStrategy' }
           AND compression = { 'chunk_length_in_kb' : 64, 'class' : 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor' }
           AND default_time_to_live = 0
           AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE'
           AND min_index_interval = 128
           AND max_index_interval = 2048
           AND crc_check_chance = 1.0;
```

How can I trace the error and specify the problem?

We are using Cassandra 3.0.8.1293

Comment: Execute query on table1 with tracing on and show us the output

Comment: How to execute with tracing?

Comment: In cqlsh use command `TRACING ON` to enable tracing in cqlsh

Comment: I've run TRACING ON and execute the query again, but I got the same error

Comment: show us the tracing log

Comment: How can I show the tracing? Is it showed on cqlsh or another file?

Comment: After you use the command `tracing on` in cqlsh, try your query in the cqlsh then tracing log will be shown in the cqlsh

Comment: the cqlsh only show the error message

Comment: Did you check the cassandra `system.log`  for any error ?

Comment: I think there are corruptions on some SSTables, but I think the error must be showed on every query. When I run the query with limit 2 it is failed but with limit 1 it is succeed.

Comment: You should check the `system.log` of each node

Comment: There is nothing strange on each node except the corruptions of SSTables on only one node

Comment: I'm in the same situation with v3.9, did you solve this problem?

Comment: @user2523216 The problem was on the SSTables files. some of them were corrupted. You can check the system.log to get the corrupted file details.